# Facing Trouble in making Android Application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

My laptop configuration is

> CPU:AMD Dual-core Processor C-60 1 ghz 2 GB DDR3 RAM WINDOWS 7 starter

So creating android application takes too much time and emulator usually goes on not responding mode. What can be optimum solution to fix it?

Can anybody suggest?

Comment: the emulator on Android is pretty much useless for real world development/debugging. You want is to get a real device to work on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes usually the emulator takes bit time to run.

What you can do is directly run your application on the actual device, thats the best solution and also finally your application should work on the actual device and not on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) running on VirtualBox/VMware

Comment: IMHO, that is not especially good advice for a Win7 PC with only 2GB of RAM.

Comment: which image i should use..if developing application on android 2.2